# VBA-JSON returning only 32,767 characters on API call

Tags: json, excel, vba

I am utilizing the latest VBA-JSON file, as of 2018 10 11, from here:

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases

While using the following code I am able to return data to the worksheet:

```
 Dim httpObject As Object
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

 sURL = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?**API Key... I can provide if necessary**"

 sRequest = sURL

 httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False
 httpObject.send
 sGetResult = httpObject.responseText

 Set oJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)

 Range("A1").Value = sGetResult
```

I have determined that it is returning 32,767 characters (not all of the data).

I have seen similar questions here on Stack Overflow that relate the issue to setting specific JSON options, but I do not see the same JSON options in the JSON file that I am using.

I've made changes from Integer to Long, but that has had no effect.

Comment: That's the excel cell character limit, nothing to do with VBA-JSON...[see here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Oh. Yeah, I see. I guess I'll search for some type of solution that maybe breaks up the result (if possible). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Smile :-)    I actually built a crypto tracker at the start of the year (and then had to get some real work done so it's been idle).

At the core was a JSON retriever and parser I wrote a few years back (with the help of StackOverflow no doubt). I'd post the zip files here but I don't think we're allowed to do that.

I'm going to submit a question in a few minutes asking someone to turn the following into an opensource / free set of VBA for anyone to use.  I've seen several questions along these lines (about JSON Parsing).

So, if you're interested -- you may find help here:  http://davidnickell.net/excel-json-parser/

Good luck and happy parsing.

Comment: I'd be crazy to NOT give it a look! Thanks so much for being so generous with your time and efforts.

Comment: My attempt to give this away "forever" fell flat ... The problem is it wasn't a question.    The location of this solution (my brand-new-never-used-wordpress-before website) could go "tilt" at any time (though I intend to evolve it).  Anyway -- anyone reading this comment who wants to take the code and make it available to others -- please feel free.    And @5th4x4 .. if you have any problems or question -- shoot me a note.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the code snippets in the page.  Sorry.

Comment: I don't know / don't think so ...  you can reach me at david@davidnickell.com